# Android SDK change MAC and IP

Tags: android, ip

Hello guys I'm new to android and want to get your help /w changing **IP** and **MAC** of android sdk.
I'm using windows OS and know how to use ADB. I thought changing 'hosts' would change ip ,but it doesnt (at least i think so)
*PS. I can't change MAC via wifi setting , cuz there is no such option at all.

I would really appreciate your help /w this.

**Thanks**